# Designer 10.0.1 Not Displaying ViewPanel Column Names

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, domino-designer-eclipse

I upgraded my designer to 10.0.1 but now not display viewpanel Column names,label etc..

[image]

Comment: Do you use a localized version or the English designer client?

Comment: Hi Torsten I have no localized Designer,Client. I'm using English designer client